# Can a PWA built in PWABuilder and Xcode receive push notifications?

Tags: xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

Can PWA apps built in using PWABuilder and Xcode receive push notifications?

The PWABuilder forum states that it still does not support such functionality and that push notifications are only available for PWAs installed through Chrome/Safari.

Answer (score 1):

PWABuilder does not work with web push currently due to Apple not allowing these notifications from anything other than a PWA that has been "added to home screen" using Safari. PWABuilder uses WKWebView, which doesn't support web push, to display the web content in a native app.

You can follow the github issue [here](https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/2434).